# Eclipse doesn't resolve includes from STL

Tags: android, c++, stl, include, openframeworks

I'm trying to build a OF android project. But it seems like Eclipse doesnt recognize STL. I tried to download it explicitly and include it, and the unresolved includes goes away then, but it seems like it still cant resolve the functions i use (tho there is a posibility that Im not linking it correctly). How do I go about solving this problem ?

Edit 1: code example

```
#include <vector>
int main(){
    std::vector<int> first(4,100);
    std::vector<int> second;
    cout << first.size();
}
```

Getting unresolved symbol on std::vector, both of them, and on cout.

On size() i get unresolved method.

It resolves the vector include tho.

Comment: What exactly did you include? My crystal ball is guessing that you erroneously wrote `#include <iostream.h>` instead of the correct `#include <iostream>`. Other than that, I'm out of guesses.

Comment: Tried to download what? And included it explicitly how? Can you post a *hello world* program and point to the lines Eclipse errors out on, and the error messages it's throwing at you?

Comment: @FredOverflow Nope, using the normal <vector> ect. I get errors on the includes otherwise.
Praetorian : I downloaded stl from here : https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/download.html

Comment: Have you tried to Google the exact error message?

Comment: yh, but most answers are very vague like " this should work, you dont need to explicitly add std" or something that doesnt take in account that this is a android project with multiple languages, not just c++.